# wind filter in opencv

Tags: image-processing, filter, opencv

Could someone suggest me how to go about getting the wind filter effect in opencv similar to the one available in photoshop and gimp?

Here is an image of text with wind styled filter applied on it. 
[image: text with wind effect]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I suggest the following steps:

Use the original text image as a mask. White pixels are '1', blacks are '0'.

Smooth the image in X direction (like    in the example image you added)

- You can do the smoothing by
  horizontal vector filter
- or use distance transform where
  distance is calculated only along x
  axis.
- I think that distance transform will
  run faster

---

Multiply the result by (1-mask) so smoothing will occur only outside the text.

Multiply each row of the result by random number in range [0.1 ..1]. This will make smoothing uneven.

Add to the result the original image of the text to get the final image